# Working example of @nativescript/firebase-firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nativescript-angular

I am trying to use the @nativescript/firebase-firestore and @nativescript/firebase-core plugin from Nativescript in my Nativescript angular project.

I ran

```js
npm install @nativescript/firebase-core

npm install @nativescript/firebase-firestore
```

and put this code to my blank native script angular project.

```js
import { firebase } from '@nativescript/firebase-core'
import '@nativescript/firebase-firestore'
const firestore = firebase().firestore()
```

I was not able to make this work for IOS due to some compatibility issues.

My questions : Has anybody put this to work and could provide me a working example?

Here is my package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "fb3",
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~15.0.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~15.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/firebase-core": "^2.5.2",
    "@nativescript/firebase-firestore": "^2.5.2",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.0.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.3.3",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.12",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~15.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

It seems that there are issues with min required iOS version is 11.0 so I added

```js
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;
```

to my build.xcconfig.

Comment: Work with IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 11.0;??